# Can I use datarepeater in microsoft visual c# 2008 express?

Tags: c#, datarepeater

I have downloaded the VIsual Basic Power packs which contain Datarepeater, I can't see it in my microsoft visual c# 2008 express.  Can I use it in the express addition?

Comment: Have you tried to include the namespace (Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks)? If you get access to the namespace, you should also have access to the DataRepeater class.

Comment: I assume access to the namespace is typing using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks?  It doesn't have the PowerPacks if this is what you meant.

Comment: In that case, see if this post will help you. It's basically the same problem with a solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbpowerpacks/thread/fd0f89a3-2a2c-4df0-9b84-3eeffde7fd2a

Comment: Thanks. I think the Visual studio service pack 1 and this only works on the full version of Visual studio c# 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual studio service pack 1 includes the data repeater. The service pack only works in the full version of Visual studio c# 2008.